# Let c be a complex number. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n=S$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cz_n = cS$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

Let c be a complex number. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n=S$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cz_n = cS$. It seems pretty trivial that you can pull out a constant from a sum, that is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cz_n=c\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n$. What does it even want me to prove??

Comment: As $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_{n}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}z_{n}$, you should use that $c\sum_{n=1}^{N}z_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}cz_{n}$ for finite sums and take the limit. Can you see what to do from here?

Comment: You are right that it’s trivial for a finite sum. You have to prove that this property extends to infinite series. I.e., you have to prove the folllwing:
$$
cS - \epsilon \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty c z_n \le cS + \epsilon
$$
For any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote by $s_{n}$ the following partial sum
\begin{align*}
s_{n} = z_{1} + z_{2} + \ldots + z_{n}
\end{align*}

To say that that $s_{n}$ converges to $s$ is the same as to say
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |s_{n} - s| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

Since the last statement is true, we can conveniently rewrite it as follows:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\left(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |s_{n} - s| < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{|c|} \Rightarrow |cs_{n} - cs| < \varepsilon\right) 
\end{align*}

whence we conclude the desired claim is true whenever $c\neq 0$. If $c = 0$, there is nothing to prove.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Why don't you distribute the c to the s term too?

Comment: @Housefire Maybe I have misunderstood your comment, but I think I did it. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes I see the correction now, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Housefire you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.